# Is it possible for a process to change it's own threads stack size?

Tags: c, makefile, stack

In a terminal I get this:

```
manu@work:ulimit -s
manu@work:8192
```

Now in a Makefile, I have

```
test:
echo `ulimit -s`
```

An running make in the same terminal gives:

```
manu@work:make test
manu@work:unlimited
```

Why ? Does the make process changes it's own threads stack size ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a thread can adjust that value, but what is strange is that it says unlimited!

Comment: Did you run the ulimit and make in separate terminals? I tested it and it worked as expected:
$ ulimit -s 1000
$ make
echo `ulimit -s`
1000

Comment: @strkol no in the same terminal as stated in the question ... this is really strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setrlimit(R_LIMIT_STACK, ...);` Alternatively, Linux also provides `prlimit` which can act as either `getlimit`, `setrlimit`, or both.